# CRTP traits only working with templated derived class

Tags: c++11, c++14

I have seen an idiom for using Derived type traits in the base class of a CRTP pattern that looks like this:

```
template<typename Derived>
struct traits;

template<typename Derived>
struct Base {
    using size_type = typename traits<Derived>::size_type;
};

template <typename T>
struct Derived1 : Base<Derived1<T>>{
    using size_type = size_t;
    void print(){ std::cout << "Derived1" << std::endl; }
};

template <typename T>
struct traits<Derived1<T>> {
    using size_type = size_t;
};

int main()
{
    using T = float;
    Derived1<T> d1;
    d1.print();
}
```

My understanding is that the purpose of the idiom is to delay the instantiation of the `Base` class's `size_type`. What I am confused by is the fact that this pattern only seems to work if the derived class is itself templated. For instance, if we change the code to:

```
template<typename Derived>
struct traits;

template<typename Derived>
struct Base {
    using size_type = typename traits<Derived>::size_type;
};

struct Derived1 : Base<Derived1>{
    using size_type = size_t;
    void print(){ std::cout << "Derived1" << std::endl; }
};

template <>
struct traits<Derived1> {
    using size_type = size_t;
};

int main()
{
    Derived1 d1;
    d1.print();
}
```

then we get the error

```
prog.cc: In instantiation of 'struct Base<Derived1>':
prog.cc:21:19:   required from here
prog.cc:18:58: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct traits<Derived1>'
     using size_type = typename traits<Derived>::size_type;
                                                          ^
prog.cc:14:8: note: declaration of 'struct traits<Derived1>'
 struct traits;
        ^~~~~~
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:33:9: error: 'Derived1' is not a template
         Derived1<float> d1;
```

Could somebody give me an explanation indicating why the templated derived class compiles, but the untemplated class does not?

Comment: "My understanding is that the purpose of the idiom is to delay the instantiation of the Base class's size_type" No, the intention for CRTP is to inject information into a class to make e.g. compile time polymorphism available. What you try to do is abuse of CRTP I believe. You are sitting on a side effect of instantiation time templates, not related to CRTP at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're seeing has nothing to do with CRTP.

Here's what the standard mentions.

> If a class template has been declared, but not defined, at the point of instantiation (13.7.4.1),
>   the instantiation yields an incomplete class type (6.7). [Example:

```
template<class T> class X; X<char> ch; // error: incomplete type
X<char>
```

Your `traits` has only been declared at the point of instantiation of `Base<Derived>`, hence as per the standard(*see above extraction from the standard*), `struct traits<Derived>` yields an incomplete type.

You should reorder the code so that it sees the `traits<Derived>` specialization when `Base<Derived>` gets instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

The compilation error you are seeing has nothing to do with CRTP, it's just a bit of a mish-mash of dependencies.

In the code without the templation, your "Base" struct needs the definition of the specialized "traits" struct but it only appears afterwards, so it tries to use the incomplete type it saw in the declaration above.

To get the code to work you need to have the "traits" specialization before the Base declaration, which requires you to also add a declaration of Derived 1, here is a compiling code:

```
class Derived1;

template<typename Derived>
struct traits;

template <>
struct traits<Derived1> {
    using size_type = size_t;
};

template<typename Derived>
struct Base {
    using size_type = typename traits<Derived>::size_type;
};

struct Derived1 : Base<Derived1>{
    using size_type = size_t;
    void print(){ std::cout << "Derived1" << std::endl; }
};


int main()
{
    Derived1 d1;
    d1.print();
}
```